# how can a function return two values

Tags: linux, fork

We know that a c function never returns more than one value.Then how come the fork() function returns two values? How it is implemented?

Comment: fork() returns two values?  Since when?

Answer (score 5):

fork() as a function only returns one value at a time - however, it creates a copy of your running executable, and returns a different value in *each copy*.

Comment: This might clarify: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html

Answer (score 4):

The `fork()` function starts a new process by duplicating the current one.  If it works, `fork()` returns one thing from the parent process and another thing from the child process so that the remaining code knows which process is "this" process.

`fork()`, in a sense, does return two values, but not in the same sense as you might be thinking.  Another function that does this type of thing is `setjmp()` (which returns `0` if returning directly and non-zero if we got here via `longjmp()`).

For a C function to return two values in the sense you're talking about, it is often done like this:

```
int return_2_values(int *other)
{
    *other = 2;
    return 1;
}
```

and invoked like this:

```
int b;
int a = return_2_values(&b);

/* a is now 1, and b is now 2 */
```

Here, `return_2_values()` is passing both return values to the same continuation, whereas `fork()` and `setjmp()` return one value each to two different continuations.

Comment: Another way you return multiple values is by returning a pointer to a structure that could then contain multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` only returns one value. It just returns *different* values different processes.

The implementation of this behavior is managed by the OS.